# Firebird EXECUTE BLOCK on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, block

How to use Firebird **execute block** statement on MySQL?

```
execute block
as
declare i int = 0;
begin
  while (i < 128) do
  begin
    insert into AsciiTable values (:i, ascii_char(:i));
    i = i + 1;
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You meant `Firebird execute block` similar thing in `MySQL`; if yes then wrap your posted code inside a `stored procedure` like below which will do the work

```
create procedure usp_test
as
begin
declare i int = 0;
  while (i < 128) do
  begin
    insert into AsciiTable values (:i, ascii_char(:i));
    i = i + 1;
  end
end
```